# CSS only: Two div with common background which change on mouse-over one of them

Tags: html, css, hover

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.body {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.square {
  width: 100vm;
  height: 100vm;
  /* For IE9 */
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: calc((100vh - 100vmin) / 2);
  background-image: url('https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB12ZJjMXXXXXa_aXXXq6xXFXXXE/3-Piece-Wall-font-b-Picture-b-font-Dreamy-font-b-Purple-b-font-font-b.jpg');
  font-size: 0;
}

.square:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
}

.square:before,
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Firefox < 16 */

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Internet Explorer */

@-ms-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Opera < 12.1 */

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.content {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 1s;
}

#left-content {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  float: left;
}

#right-content {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  float: right;
}

#left-content:after {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  float: left;
  opacity: 0;
  content: ' ';
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#right-content:after {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  float: right;
  opacity: 0;
  content: ' ';
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#left-content:hover:after+.square {
  background-image: url('https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1EuKlLVXXXXcmXpXXq6xXFXXXd/E-HOME-Stretched-LED-Canvas-Print-Blue-Rose-Flash-Effect-LED-Flashing-font-b-Optical-b.jpg');
  opacity: 1;
}

#right-content:hover:after {
  background-image: url('https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB12hyVPVXXXXbEaXXXq6xXFXXX8/-font-b-Canvas-b-font-Painting-Printed-Pictures-Paints-Wall-Hanging-font-b-Canvas-b.jpg');
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content">
        <a href="">
          <div id="left-content"></div>
        </a>
        <a href="">
          <div id="right-content"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like to do the following.

DIV container contains two DIV (1 and 2).
When mouse is over DIV 1, the background image of DIV CONTAINER change to image1.
When mouse is over DIV 2, the background image of DIV CONTAINER change to image2.

I would like to try this with only CSS.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to insert it. Just added it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Tymek/yrKRX/    here you have an idea

Comment: I tried your example using my design but it doesn't work. Will continue to investigate.

Comment: you can achieve what you want easily using Jquery @yoan26

Comment: I think this is not possible. You need the ':has' selector, which is not supported by any browser at this time. [http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has)

Comment: Ok it is possible. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body { width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
.div1, .div2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
  color: hsla(0, 57.6%, 50%, 0.5);
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
}
.background1, .background2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: -1;
}
.background1 {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/zFYHM67.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.background2 {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/nYKEFNF.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.div1:hover ~ .background1 {
  display: flex;
}
.div2:hover ~ .background2 {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">Div 1</div>
  <div class="background1"></div>
  <div class="div2">Div 2</div>
  <div class="background2"></div>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/k652snyc/

Comment: Thanks! even better with background-image concept :)

Answer (score 1):

So it is actually possible with pseudo elements. Have a look at my example.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#main:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#main {
  height: 170px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

#div1 .show {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#div1:hover:before, #div2:hover:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#div1:hover:before {
  background: yellow;
}

#div2:hover:before {
  background: green;
}

#div1, #div2 {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.show {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 168px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="div1">
    <div class="show">
      div1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <div class="show">
      div2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Working ideed! Thanks a lot!